# I can not find anything in the specification regarding "native" clause

Tags: dart

I can not find anything in the language specification regarding "native" clause. Who can explain me where this defined as part of language?

Code example written in Dart language:

```dart
double get defaultValue native "AudioParam_defaultValue_Getter";
```

I know that this intended for writing wrappers to native code but I cannot find  where this defined that this is a valid language element.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an implementation detail and is not (yet) part of the spec.

I'd open a bug to track this. I could imagine others wanted create code that uses native.

See here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7703